# Java: Generics capture error

Tags: java, generics, capture

I'm trying to make the following code work with no success

```
protected BackgroundTask<?> backgroundTask = null;

...

protected <T> void confirmBackgroundAction(final BackgroundTask<T> task, final T arg) {
   backgroundTask = task;
   backgroundTask.attach(AbstractWorkerActivity.this);
   backgroundTask.execute(arg);
}
```

Capture class looks like this:

```
public abstract class BackgroundTask<T> extends AsyncTask<T, Void, Long> {
...
}
```

With this code I'm having the following compilation error:

```
The method execute(capture#26-of ?...) in the type AsyncTask<capture#26-of ?,Void,Long> is not applicable for the arguments (T)
```

If I replace

```
backgroundTask.execute(arg);
```

with

```
((BackgroundTask<T>)backgroundTask).execute(arg);
```

I'm not having any compilation error anymore, but I have a ClassCastException at Runtime.
Is there a way to pass an instance of the BackgroundTask + the argument to my function ?

Edit: I forget the code from where I call the confirmBackgroundAction() method...

```
confirmBackgroundAction(new SpecificBackgroundTask(), (Void) null);
```

Where SpecificBackgroundTask looks like

```
public class SpecificBackgroundTask extends BackgroundTask<Void> {
...
}
```

Comment: Does it work when you don't assign to `backgroundTask` but use a method variable of type `BackgroundTask<T>`?

Comment: No more compilation error, but I got the same Class cast exception...
And I need to assign the task to backgroundTask

Comment: Can provide a [sscce](http://pscode.org/sscce.html)? ie simplify your code down to the essence of the problem, using standard JDK classes where possible so we can try to get it to work in our IDEs. And provide how you want the calling code to look.

Comment: `BackgroundTask<T> backgroundTask` can only keep 1 type of argument *and* call the `execute(T arg)` method correctly. So unless you can abstract it down into usage of `interface`s what you try might be impossible.

Comment: can you provide the stack trace of the class cast exception?

Comment: What happens if you change `backgroundTask.execute(arg)` to `task.execute(arg)`?

Comment: @rsp: yes BackgroundTask<T> can only hold a single type and that's exactly what I'm using here. I just edited my post with the call of the confirmBackgroundTask() and as you can see I'm using the Void type.

Comment: @Matt This is a ClassCastException
((BackgroundTask<T>)backgroundTask).execute(arg);
failed to resolve arg as Void type

Comment: @ruakh : just look at my 1st answer to rsp. It solves the compilation error but I'm still having the ClassCastException

Comment: @user1026605: I think the problem is probably in `SpecificBackgroundTask.execute(Void)`, which you haven't posted. But you haven't posted the stacktrace of your `ClassCastException`, so it's impossible to say for sure.

Comment: @ruakh as I said the problem is that in the call ((BackgroundTask<T>)backgroundTask).execute(arg);
 arg isn't solved as Void type !
SpecificBackgroundTask is an Android Asynctask and i didn't override it. My problem is with the use of the generics not vith the call of the SpecificBackgroundTask.execute() method.
If I call ((BackgroundTask<T>)backgroundTask).execute((Void)arg); 
casting arg in Void it works...

Comment: @user1026605: That doesn't make sense. Can you post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html)?

Comment: At compile time, the `T` in `BackgroundTask<T>` is unknown and can at most (theoretically) store 1 type `T` of multiple possible types with which you can call `confirmBackgroundAction`. The compiler has no way to solve this consistently. Changing `T` into an `interface` you define would fix the ambiguity.

Comment: @rsp: thanks! How can I validate your comment as a valid answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At compile time, the `T` in `BackgroundTask<T>` is unknown and can at most (theoretically) store 1 type T of multiple possible types with which you can call `confirmBackgroundAction()`.

The compiler has no way to solve this consistently. Changing `T` into an `interface` you define would fix the ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
class Klass {


  protected BackgroundTask<?> backgroundTask = null;

...

  protected <T> void confirmBackgroundAction(final BackgroundTask<T> task, Object arg) {
     backgroundTask = task;
     backgroundTask.attach(AbstractWorkerActivity.this);
     backgroundTask.execute( (T) arg);
  }
}
```

Comment: No I can't fix <T>... Every call to this function can use a different type

Comment: OK. misunderstood your need, then try the edited version above

Comment: No still no luck ;)
I'm still having a ClassCastException